# Nested dictionary value from key path

Tags: python, dictionary

Get the value from a nested dictionary with the help of key path, here is the `dict`:

```
json = {
    "app": {
        "Garden": {
            "Flowers": {
                "Red flower": "Rose",
                "White Flower": "Jasmine",
                "Yellow Flower": "Marigold"
            }
        },
        "Fruits": {
            "Yellow fruit": "Mango",
            "Green fruit": "Guava",
            "White Flower": "groovy"
        },
        "Trees": {
            "label": {
                "Yellow fruit": "Pumpkin",
                "White Flower": "Bogan"
            }
        }
    }
```

The input parameter to the method is the key path with dots separated, from the key path = "app.Garden.Flowers.white Flower" need to print 'Jasmine'. My code so far:

```
import json
with open('data.json') as data_file:    
  j = json.load(data_file)


def find(element, JSON):     
  paths = element.split(".")  
  # print JSON[paths[0]][paths[1]][paths[2]][paths[3]]
  for i in range(0,len(paths)):
    data = JSON[paths[i]]
    # data = data[paths[i+1]]
    print data



find('app.Garden.Flowers.White Flower',j)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very close. You need to (as you had in your comment) recursively go through the main JSON object. You can accomplish that by storing the result of the outermost key/value, then using that to get the next key/value, etc. till you're out of paths.

```
def find(element, JSON):     
  paths = element.split(".")
  data = JSON
  for i in range(0,len(paths)):
    data = data[paths[i]]
  print data
```

You still need to watch out for KeyErrors though.

Answer (score 70):

This is an instance of a [fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)). You can either write it concisely like this:

```
from functools import reduce
import operator

def find(element, json):
    return reduce(operator.getitem, element.split('.'), json)
```

Or more Pythonically (because [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) is frowned upon due to poor readability) like this:

```
def find(element, json):
    keys = element.split('.')
    rv = json
    for key in keys:
        rv = rv[key]
    return rv

j = {"app": {
    "Garden": {
        "Flowers": {
            "Red flower": "Rose",
            "White Flower": "Jasmine",
            "Yellow Flower": "Marigold"
        }
    },
    "Fruits": {
        "Yellow fruit": "Mango",
        "Green fruit": "Guava",
        "White Flower": "groovy"
    },
    "Trees": {
        "label": {
            "Yellow fruit": "Pumpkin",
            "White Flower": "Bogan"
        }
    }
}}
print find('app.Garden.Flowers.White Flower', j)
```

Comment: Instead of defining your own item-getter function using lambda, you can `import operator` and use `operator.getitem`.

Comment: If you want to address an item by an integer index (app.Garden.Flowers.0), you may change your for-loop like this: try: rv = rv[int(key)] except: rv = rv[key] – n.r. 4 mins ago   Edit

Comment: this solution doesnt support list ,If you change Flowers to be list - u get an error

Comment: @n.r. had a good suggestion but I don't like using try-except for control flow. You could also use a ternary and convert the key if `type(rv) is list`.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you to use `python-benedict`, a python dict subclass with full keypath support and many utility methods.

You just need to cast your existing dict:

```
d = benedict(json)
# now your keys support dotted keypaths
print(d['app.Garden.Flower.White Flower'])
```

Here the library and the documentation:
https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/python-benedict

Note: I am the author of this project

Answer (score 3):

Your code heavily depends on no dots every occurring in the key names, which you might be able to control, but not necessarily.

I would go for a generic solution using a list of element names and then generate the list e.g. by splitting a dotted list of key names:

```
class ExtendedDict(dict):
    """changes a normal dict into one where you can hand a list
    as first argument to .get() and it will do a recursive lookup
    result = x.get(['a', 'b', 'c'], default_val)
    """
    def multi_level_get(self, key, default=None):
        if not isinstance(key, list):
            return self.get(key, default)
        # assume that the key is a list of recursively accessible dicts
        def get_one_level(key_list, level, d):
            if level >= len(key_list):
                if level > len(key_list):
                    raise IndexError
                return d[key_list[level-1]]
            return get_one_level(key_list, level+1, d[key_list[level-1]])

        try:
            return get_one_level(key, 1, self)
        except KeyError:
            return default

    get = multi_level_get # if you delete this, you can still use the multi_level-get
```

Once you have this class it is easy to just transform your dict and get "Jasmine":

```
json = {
        "app": {
            "Garden": {
                "Flowers": {
                    "Red flower": "Rose",
                    "White Flower": "Jasmine",
                    "Yellow Flower": "Marigold"
                }
            },
            "Fruits": {
                "Yellow fruit": "Mango",
                "Green fruit": "Guava",
                "White Flower": "groovy"
            },
            "Trees": {
                "label": {
                    "Yellow fruit": "Pumpkin",
                    "White Flower": "Bogan"
                }
            }
        }
    }

j = ExtendedDict(json)
print j.get('app.Garden.Flowers.White Flower'.split('.'))
```

will get you:

```
Jasmine
```

Like with a normal `get()` from a dict, you get `None` if the key (list) you specified doesn't exists anywhere in the tree, and you can specify a second parameter as return value instead of `None`

Answer (score 2):

one-liner:

```
from functools import reduce

a = {"foo" : { "bar" : "blah" }}
path = "foo.bar"

reduce(lambda acc,i: acc[i], path.split('.'), a)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1: pyats library from Cisco [its a c extension]**

- Its quick and Super fast (measure it with timeit if required)
- Javascript-ish usage [Bracket lookup ,dotted lookup, combined lookup]
- Dotted Lookup for missing key raises Attribute error, bracket or default python dict lookup gives KeyError.

```
pip install pyats pyats-datastructures pyats-utils
```

```
from pyats.datastructures import NestedAttrDict
item = {"specifications": {"os": {"value": "Android"}}}
path = "specifications.os.value"
x = NestedAttrDict(item)
print(x[path])# prints Android
print(x['specifications'].os.value)# prints Android
print(x['specifications']['os']['value'])#prints Android
print(x['specifications'].os.value1)# raises Attribute Error
```

**Option 2:pyats.utils chainget**

- super fast (measure it with timeit if required)

```
from pyats.utils import utils
item = {"specifications": {"os": {"value": "Android"}}}
path = "specifications.os.value"
path1 = "specifications.os.value1"
print(utils.chainget(item,path))# prints android (string version)
print(utils.chainget(item,path.split('.')))# prints android(array version)
print(utils.chainget(item,path1))# raises KeyError
```

**Option 3: python without external library**

1. Better speed in comparison to lambda.
2. Separate Error handling not required as in lambda and other cases.
3. Readable and concise can be a utils function/helper in the project

```
from functools import reduce
item = {"specifications": {"os": {"value": "Android"}}}
path1 = "specifications.family.value"
path2 = "specifications.family.value1"

def test1():
    print(reduce(dict.get, path1.split('.'), item))

def test2():
    print(reduce(dict.get, path2.split('.'), item))

test1() # prints Android
test2() # prints None
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrote function that works with lists in dict.

```
d = {'test': [
    {'value1': 'val'},
    {'value1': 'val2'}]}


def find_element(keys: list, dictionary: dict):
    rv = dictionary
    if isinstance(dictionary, dict):
        rv = find_element(keys[1:], rv[keys[0]])
    elif isinstance(dictionary, list):
        if keys[0].isnumeric():
            rv = find_element(keys[1:], dictionary[int(keys[0])])
    else:
        return rv
    return rv


val = find_element('test.1.value1'.split('.'), d)
```

Answer (score -1):

data:

```
data = {
    "data": {
        "author_id": "1",
        "text": "hi msg",
        "attachments": {
            "media_keys": [
                "3_16"
            ]
        },
        "id": "2",
        "edit_history_tweet_ids": [
            "2"
        ]
    },
    "includes": {
        "media": [
            {
                "media_key": "3_16",
                "height": 500,
                "type": "photo",
                "width": 500,
                "url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/xxxxxx.png"
            }
        ],
        "users": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "name1",
                "username": "username1"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

function:

```
def get_value_from_dict(dic_obj, keys: list, default):
    """
    get value from dict with key path.
    :param dic_obj: dict
    :param keys: dict key
    :param default: default value
    :return:
    """
    if not dic_obj or not keys:
        return default

    pre_obj = dic_obj
    for key in keys:
        t = type(pre_obj)
        if t is dict:
            pre_obj = pre_obj.get(key)
        elif (t is list or t is tuple) and str(key).isdigit() and len(pre_obj) > int(key):
            pre_obj = pre_obj[int(key)]
        else:
            return default
    return pre_obj
```

test:

```
print('media_key:', get_value_from_dict(data, 'data.attachments.media_keys'.split('.'), None))
print('username:', get_value_from_dict(data, 'includes.users.0.username'.split('.'), None))
```

```
media_key: ['3_16']
username: username1
```