# How to call get() on dictionary with indexes?

Tags: python

I have an array of dictionaries but i am running into a scenario where I have to get the value from 1st index of the array of dictionaries, following is the chunk that I am trying to query.

```
address_data = record.get('Rdata')[0].get('Adata')
```

This throws the following error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I tried following:

```
if record.get('Rdata') and record.get('Rdata')[0].get('Adata'):
   address_data = record.get('Rdata')[0].get('Adata')
```

but I don't know if the above approach is good or not.

So how to handle this in python?

**Edit:**

```
"partyrecord": {

      "Rdata": [
        {

          "Adata": [
            {
              "partyaddressid": 172,
              "addressid": 142165
            }
          ]

        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what `address_data` looks like?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31033549/nested-dictionary-value-from-key-path

Comment: You can one-line this: `address_data = bool(record.get('Rdata')) and record.get('Rdata')[0].get('Adata') or None` -  you can replace `None` with whatever fallback value you want

Comment: We need to see what `record` loops like, not `address_data`

Comment: @JacobIRR `len(record.get('Rdata'))` immediately fails if the value doesn't exist because it becomes `len(None)`

Comment: `record.get('Rdata')` this is returning `None`. You need to break up this statement to handle that case

Comment: @JacobIRR Wouldn't that just return 1 or 0 and not the actual value inside the dict?

Comment: @roganjosh ,  i have posted some sample

Comment: @JacobIRR you've fixed the error, but no need for `bool` now :) `None` is falsey, so just `if record.get('Rdata') and...` but even then, you can return an empty dict if the first lookup fails

Comment: I see the example but it's disembodied from the problem you describe. There is no `Rdata` key. Please give a [mcve]. The level of nesting for `record` is too deep for your approach to work with that sample.

Comment: @noobie-php, your proposed solution seems ok to me.  It avoids the issue mentioned in the comments because `if record.get('Rdata')` checks both for the record 'Rdata' to exist in 'record', and for it to reference a container that has something in it.  So you should safely be able to say `record.get('Rdata')[0]` if this test succeeds. (assuming your assumptions about your data are otherwise correct).

Comment: @noobie-php, ...now, about your data...first of all, I assume you want a pair of curly braces around what you've given us, as what you have here isn't legal Python by itself.  what do you want to do exactly with this data?

Answer (score 4):

Your expression assumes that `record['Rdata']` will return a list with at least one element, so provide one if that isn't the case.

```
address_data = record.get('Rdata', [{}])[0].get('Adata')
```

Now if `record['Rdata']` doesn't exist, you'll still have an empty `dict` on which to invoke `get('Adata')`. The end result will be `address_data` being set to `None`.

(Checking for the key first is preferable if a suitable default is expensive to create, since it will be created whether `get` needs to return it or not. But `[{}]` is fairly lightweight, and the compiler can generate it immediately.)

Answer (score 3):

You might want to go for the simple, not exciting route:

```
role_data = record.get('Rdata')

if role_data:
  address_data = role_data[0].get('Adata')
else:
  address_data = None
```

Comment: This fails if there is role_data but it isn't an iterable. I guess we can assume it will be

Comment: It may be OK to assume that `record` is well-formed, but that `Rdata` is simply optional, rather than accommodating every possible `dict`. (We're also assuming that `record` has a `get` method in the first place.)