# Look up data in a nested dictionary using a path of keys

Tags: python

I am trying to look up data in nested Python dictionaries by giving a path of keys.

For example, if my dict is

```
my_dict = {"key1": {"key2": 'my data'}}
```

I want to access `my_dict['key1']['key2']` by giving the path `'key1|key2'`

Here is what I tried:

```
all_keys = "key1|key2"
keys = all_keys.split("|")
key_path = ""
for key in keys:
     key_path += '[\'' + key + '\']'
     #my_dict is a dictionary with other dictionaries within it
     returnval = my_dict + key_path
```

I am getting the error:  `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'str'`

Comment: `dict` is a type, don't call your variable like this, choose another name

Comment: question is not clear. what is the intended output here? Please specify your desired input and output clearly

Comment: I *think* you're expecting `dict + key_path` to magically become e.g. `dict['key1']`, which absolutely **will not happen**. You could make and evaluate that string, but why not just `dict[key]`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I want to make a function that accepts all_keys (keys concatenated using pipe operator) and finds the key value, so I am not directly using dict['key1']

Comment: But you seem to be trying, unnecessarily and in a manner that cannot work, to build that expression as a string. The point is you can already use the value of a string as a key, using the notation I showed above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using [functools.reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce

nested = {"key1": {"key2": 'my data'}}

all_keys = "key1|key2"
key_path = all_keys.split("|")

data = reduce(lambda dct, key: dct[key], key_path, nested)
print(data)
# my data
```

Comment: Unbelievable. I was just trying to understand the question. And you have already answered it :)

Comment: @Thierry Lathuille Thank you, this worked as I expected.

Comment: key error. with lambda. replace lambda dict.get. answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66761659/2223689

Answer (score 0):

This is a common beginner problem: confusing language syntax with data.  You can do this with the `eval` function family, but ... don't, as it's prone to painful error.  Rather, iterate through your list of keys:

```
local_val = my_dict   # whatever is at your top level
keys = [ , , ]  # Your list of keys, top-down order
for local_key in keys:
    local_val = local_val[key]

# On loop exit, local_val is the innermost value you referenced.
```

Answer (score 0):

dict+'["hello"]["world"]' will throw an error. That is not the way to access dict["hello"]["world"]. The plus symbol doesn't function that way in python, and this is why you're getting the error `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'str'`

Python doesn't know how to add a dictionary and a string!

`all_keys = "key1|key2"
keys = all_keys.split("|")
returnval=dict   #keep the top level stored in returnval initially
for key in keys:
    returnval=returnval[key]  #go down one level
print(returnval)`

Also, please don't name your dictionary 'dict'. It's also a class name, so it is generally bad practice. Try mydict,d etc.