# Python Index Nested Dictionary with List

Tags: python, list, dictionary

If I have a nested dictionary and varying lists:

```
d = {'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': 0}}}}
list1 = ['a', 'b']
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list3 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

How can I access dictionary values like so:

```
>>> d[list1]
{'c': {'d': 0}}
>>> d[list3]
0
```

Comment: while not a strict duplicate, this is a close match: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31033549/758174

Comment: good point, couldn't find that googling!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use functools reduce. info [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#module-functools). You have a nice post on reduce in [real python](https://realpython.com/python-reduce-function/)

```py
from functools import reduce

reduce(dict.get, list3, d)
>>> 0
```

**EDIT: mix of list and dictioanries**

in case of having mixed list and dictionary values the following is possible

```
d = {'a': [{'b0': {'c': 1}}, {'b1': {'c': 1}}]}
list1 = ['a', 1, 'b1', 'c']

fun = lambda element, indexer: element[indexer]
reduce(fun, list1, d)
>>> 1
```

Comment: This is a great answer. But I realize it doesn't work if you have lists in your dictionary like so `d = {'a': [{'b0': {'c': 1}}, {'b1': {'c': 1}}]}` and a list like so `['a', 1, 'c']`

Comment: It is possible let me make an edit

Comment: actually is possible if your list is as follow ['a', 1, 'b1' 'c'], would that pass? In any case I have added an edit

Comment: legendary .....

Comment: you can check the real python post whenever you have time, is quite nice, reduce can be very useful!

Answer (score 2):

Use a short function:

```
def nested_get(d, lst):
    out = d
    for x in lst:
        out = out[x]
    return out

nested_get(d, list1)
# {'c': {'d': 0}}
```